# Member with the same signature is already declared

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I know what it means but want elegant solution to this problem. For a work around solution, I can create methods with different signatures, but that won't satisfy me.
My scenario is as below:

```
public interface IDomainToViewMapper<TModel, TViewModel>
{
    TViewModel MapDomainToView(TModel source);
}

public interface ISiteMapper : IDomainToViewMapper<Site, ViewModelOne>,
                               IDomainToViewMapper<Site, ViewModelTwo>
{    }
```

Now when I write my main implementation class, I get member with same signature issue. I can go ahead and implement interface explicitly, but because we are injecting dependencies on the fly, I can't cast to interface, which will again be ambiguous.

```
    public SiteMapper : ISiteMapper
{
    public ViewModelOne MapDomainToView(Site site) { ... }
    public ViewModelTwo MapDomainToView(Site site) { ... }      
}
```

Any elegant solution to the issue would be great

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah, it's ambigious and if C# permitted, I could have cast the return value to either ViewModelOne and ViewModelTwo and it could have executed appropriate method. I can write MapToViewModelTwo method in ISiteMapper and so on, but I thought let me pick brain and see if there is any way out of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SiteMapper is basically a **Factory** if I understand your design, make your SiteMapper method MapDomainToView **return a list of ViewModels for a given Site**, add a method where you can Register ViewModels for a specific Site, store this mapping in a Dictionary for example.

Or use **Castle Windsor** or your favorite IoC container in stead of SiteMapper or possibly internally in SiteMapper

Example:

```
public interface IViewModel
{
}

public class ViewModelOne : IViewModel
{
}

public class ViewModelTwo : IViewModel
{
}


public class SiteMapper 
{
    private Dictionary<Site, List<IViewModel>> map { get; set; }

    public void Register(Site site, IViewModel viewModel)
    {
        // Add combination to map
    }

    public List<IViewModel> MapDomainToViews(Site site) 
    {
        if (map.ContainsKey(site))
            return map[site];
        else
            ....
    }
}
```

This is a simple IoC, if you go this route check out Castle, Unity, NInject etc

Comment: thanks, your solution is definitely one to look into, but in my present situation, involves bit of change. Am going with renaming the method like MapToViewModelOne, MapToViewModelTwo and the rest. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is because c# does not allow you to overload methods based solely on the return type - only the method parameters are considered when determining whether two methods have the same signature or not.

The only solution is to tweak your API design a bit.

**EDIT**: Sorry, as I reread your question, I realized you already know the cause of the error and are looking for how to redesign your API. So please ignore my answer!

Comment: how can I tweak my API design a bit, which gives me elegant solution. Considering Site is the main domain class, there will be many view using this class to get it's viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have in essence one method which can decide based on just one given parameter which of the (many/two) view models to return the most elegant solution will be to define just one method returning superclass of your ViewModel (exactly as defined in your interface)

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you're introducing unnecessary complexity by having Library and Shelf as classes rather than record struct types. E.G.:

```
public record struct Shelf(int Id, string Name, int Cost, int Price, List<Book> Books);
```

and

```
public record struct Library(int Id, string Name, int Cost, int Price, List<Shelf> Shelves);
```

Besides reducing boilerplate, I'd expect that this would allow the compiler to take of performance better than you can by hand.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).